# How do I simplify factorials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Given the following equation:

$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}*\frac{1}{n^{k}}=\frac{1}{k!}*\frac{n*(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{n^{k}}$$

(I used * as the multiplication sign).

I understand $\frac{1}{k!}$ but $$\frac{n*(n-1)*...*(n-k+1)}{n^{k}}$$ is a problem for me. I also understand why $n^{k}$ is in the denominator. I specifically do not understand what happened to $n!$ and $(n-k)!$

Comment: I'd recommend not using $*$ for multiplication. It has other important uses in mathematics. $n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$ or even $\prod_{i=0}^{k+1}{n-i}$ would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you mean is 
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = \frac{1 \times 2 \times \ldots \times n}{1 \times 2 \times \ldots \times (n-k)} = n (n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)  = P(n, k)
$$
Also note that this product can bounded: 
$$
P(n,k) = n^k \times (1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n}) \ldots (1-\frac{k-1}{n}) \leq n^k
$$

Comment: The first part of your answer answers exactly what I did not understand, however I still do not understand $$\frac{1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot n}{1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot (n-k)} = n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$$

Comment: Hint: $n-1 = n(1-\frac{1}{n}) < n$

Comment: I am sorry but I sort of do not see the connection. Usually when you have a factorial divided by another factorial where the numerator is bigger than the denominator (for example $\frac{5!}{3!}$) you can reduce the fraction by all terms  $\leq 3$ (refering to the example) right? Well yeah that sort of is all I can think of, would you mind giving me a full explanation?

Comment: $\frac{5!}{3!} = 5 \times 4 < 5 \times 5 = 5^2$. IS this clear? I gave you an simple upper bound on the product.

Comment: Well yes I understand $\frac{5!}{3!}=5\cdot4<5\cdot5=5^{2}$ . But I do not see the connection to $$\frac{1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot n}{1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot (n-k)}=n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$$

Comment: Replace $5$ with $n$ and $3$ with $n-k$

Comment: If we go through the equation with $5!$ and $3!$ then we would have $$5(5-1)(5-2)(5-3+1)$$ if we use $n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$ but that would equal $180$ instead of $120$. Where do I think wrongly?

Comment: No in your case $k=2$, not 3, so you would have $\frac{5!}{(5-2)!} = (5-2+1)(5-2+2)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108824/discussion-between-math-noob-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

Notice if $m > n$ then $\frac {m!}{n!} = \frac {1*2*3*4*........*n*(n+1)*......m}{1*2*3*4*......*n} = \frac {(1*2*3*4*......*n)*[(n+1)*.....m])}{1*2*3*4*......*n}=(n+1)*.....m$

So $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}*\frac{1}{n^{k}}=$

$\frac 1{k!}*\frac 1{n^k} * \frac {n!}{(n-k)!} =\frac 1{k!}*\frac 1{n^k} *\frac {[1*2*3 *......*(n-k)]*[(n-k+1)*(n-k+2)*......*n]}{1*2*3 *......*(n-k)}=\frac 1{k!}*\frac 1{n^k}(n-k+1)*(n-k+2)*......*n$